# how to create a custom control for a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, custom-controls

Hai Freinds

So far i have used this coding to create a custom Control as my knowledge in the pervious post.i dono it is correct or not.I need a further help regarding this.so far i have used this coding the appcode->Number.cs in that i have used this coding further what should i do: my requriements is that i drag the textbox in the controls only number should be entered in that. for reference see my previous post:http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10200401/how-to-create-a-dll-file-for-the-textbox-with-some-requriments.aspx.i need it in web applications

```
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;    
using System.Web.UI;    
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;    
using System.Xml.Linq;

/// <summary>     
/// Summary description for Number    
/// </summary> 
public class Number : TextBox    
{    
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)     
    {    
        base.OnKeyPress(e);     
        if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9')     
        {    
            e.Handled = false;        
        }   
        else 
        {    
            e.Handled = true;     
        }  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have created the same type of control for our need. We used js file for that.
The following function only allows numbers.

Please use this link to create a custom control http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CreateNumTextBoxControl.aspx

```
   function CheckOnlyInteger(e, sender, allowNegative) {
    e = e || window.event;
    //var key = (window.event) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var key = e ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //alert(key);
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        if ((key > 47 && key < 58) || (key == 192) || (key >= 37 && key <= 39) || key == 0)     {
        return false;
      }
   }
   if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || // 0-9 numbers
    (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || // Left, Up, Right and Down
    key == 8 || // backspaceASKII
    key == 9 || // tabASKII
    key == 16 || // shift
    key == 17 || // control
    (key >= 96 && key <= 105) || (key == 46)) // || // Home  key == 46) // dotASKII
{
    return true;
}
 else if ((key == 45) && (allowNegative == 'true')) { // dash (-)       
    if (sender.value.indexOf('-') > -1) {
        return false;
    }
     else {
        if (sender.value.indexOf('-') == 0) {
            return true;
         }
         else {
            sender.value = sender.value.replace('-', '');
            sender.value = "-" + sender.value;
            return true;
         } //alert(key + ' ' + sender.value + ' ' + allowNegative);    alert((key == 45) && (allowNegative == true));
    }
}
else
    return false;
 }


  public partial class ANTextBox: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox 
    {
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        ClientScriptManager scriptMananger = this.Page.ClientScript;
        string resourceFilePath = "TBControlLibrary.Resources.AlphaNumeric.js";

        scriptMananger.RegisterClientScriptInclude("ANTextBox", scriptMananger.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), resourceFilePath));

        if (this.Type == TextBoxType.Integer)
        {                
            if (_AllowNegative) { this.Text = "-"; }
            this.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", string.Format("return CheckOnlyInteger(event,this,'{0}');", _AllowNegative.ToString().ToLower()));               
        }
     }
```

Comment: i wnat this a a textbox control so that it will be easy to drag and drop the control

Comment: Create a class library for textbox. Use this js there.  [assembly: WebResource("TBControlLibrary.Resources.AlphaNumeric.js", "text/javascript")]